# How To Get Line From Multiline Textbox to single textbox?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

[THAT'S PREVIEW APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqH09.jpg)

how to get the last line eg: DD D5 08 0C 0C 20 08 00 90 00 from multiline text box to single textbox,

i want when i click button 1 i get just last result (DD D5 08 0C 0C 20 08 00 90 00) to single textbox

pleaze help me dear

my code is look like :

```
Public Sub displayOut(ByVal errorType As Integer, ByVal returnValue As Integer, ByVal printText As String)

    TextBoxLogs.Text += printText & vbCrLf
    TextBoxLogs.SelectionStart = TextBoxLogs.Text.Length
    TextBoxLogs.ScrollToCaret()
    TextBoxLogs.Refresh()

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonGetCardInfo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonGetCardInfo.Click

    displayOut(1, 0, "Card unique serial number")
    'CardCommands.getCardUniqueSerialNumber()

    If Not Common.isSuccessful Then
        Return
    End If

  End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Common.clearBuffers()

    Common.sendBuff(0) = &H80   'CLA
    Common.sendBuff(1) = &H14   'INS
    Common.sendBuff(2) = &H0    'P1
    Common.sendBuff(3) = &H0    'P2
    Common.sendBuff(4) = &H8    'LE

    Common.sendLen = 5
    Common.recvLen = 255

    Common.returnCode = Common.sendApdu(2)

    ErrorCodes.interpretReturnStatus()

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesnt look like you have tried anything or poked around TextBox properties at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Lines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the MultiLine TextBox...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SingleTextBox.Text = TextBoxLogs.Lines(TextBoxLogs.Lines.GetUpperBound(0))
End Sub
```

If you may have an indeterminate number of blank lines at the end of the TextBox, then walk the Lines() array **backwards** until you find the first non-blank one:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = TextBoxLogs.Lines.GetUpperBound(0) To 0 Step -1
        If TextBoxLogs.Lines(i).Trim <> "" Then
            SingleTextBox.Text = TextBoxLogs.Lines(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: is not work but i have done when i change code like this :

SingleTextBox.Text = TextBoxLogs.Lines(TextBoxLogs.Lines.GetUpperBound(0) - 1)

@idle_Mind Thanks a lot

Comment: Although this may have helped the OP, but the OP clearly didn't show an attempt at what he was trying to do. SO is for helping people that are ***stuck on specific issues***, not a ask and we'll give the codes site. The issue we face by answering these incomplete and non verifiable questions is others assume it is ok do this and it's not...

Comment: You must have had a **BLANK** line at the end of the TextBox then.